# Rasterizing lines with “gdal_rasterize” in R return no result and status 1

Tags: shapefile, gdal, r, rasterization, gdalutils

I am using `gdal_rasterize` in the gdalUtils [package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gdalUtils/index.html) to convert lines in a Shapefile to a raster.

```
library(gdalUtils)
src <- "D:/Test/sample.shp"
dst <- "D:/Test/raster.tif"
raster <- gdal_rasterize(src,dst, tr = c(20,20), verbose = T)
```

The function runs and returns a warning "had status 1" and no raster is produced in the destination folder.

```
Checking gdal_installation...
GDAL command being used: "D:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\gdal_rasterize.exe" -tr 20 20 "D:/Test/sample.shp" "D:/Test/raster.tif"
Warning message:
running command '"D:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\gdal_rasterize.exe" -tr 20 20 "D:/Test/sample.shp" "D:/Test/raster.tif"' had status 1
```

Am I missing something? This seems like it should be very simple

Comment: What is the projection of your sample.shp? If is happens to be EPSG:4326 then pixel size of 20x20 degrees may cause troubles.

Comment: @user30184 EPSG:27700, OSGB 1936 / British National Grid

Comment: @user30184 Sorry you are right, at some point, the file has been changed to EPSG:4326 what should I use.

Comment: You can stay with EPSG:4326 if you wish but try without -tr that seems to be an optional parameter http://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html. Or perhaps -tr 0.0001 could make sense.

Comment: How about applying **ogr2ogr()** with **t_srs** on the *sample.shp*,  before performing rasterize?

Comment: @user30184 tried both didn't change anything

Comment: @Kazuhito tried that as well, but its just a link to the file not an object itself

Comment: What does raster(shapefile(src), res = 20) give you?  Is that resolution sensible for the given input?

Comment: @mdsumner it creates an empty raster, The resolution is sensible because I can run it in QGIS with no problem

Comment: @falcs I could reproduce the error, and somehow managed to escape from it. I had to (1) set `a = "my_data"`, and (2) change the extension of target raster from **.tif** to **.tiff**...Note on (1),  one attribute name of Shapefile was required. Note on (2), I do not know why but **gdal_rasterize()** did not recognize **.tif**. Probably this was the reason of `status 1` error message. Not sure this applies to your case, though.

Comment: @Kazuhito a partial fix, I can now produce a raster, but it is blank

Comment: @falcs Many thanks, I will try your **ts** solution at my end, too.

Comment: @falcs I can only take your word for it, if you provided sufficient detail I would have checked for myself and reported back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of @Kazuhito I have a fix

```
library(gdalUtils)
src <- "D:/test/line.shp"
dst <- "D:/test/raster.tiff"
raster <- gdal_rasterize(src,dst, ts = c(1500,800), a = "my_data", verbose = T)
```

Key problems seem to be that gdal_rasterize does not like .tif but will work with .tiff and that the tr (target resolution) function does not work however working out the appropriate size (ts) and specifying that does work.